# MySQL server has gone execute large script files

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver, navicat

Please help me to get rid of this errors
While i run some large number of mysql scripts at once i got this kind of errors

> ERROR: 2006  MySQL server has gone away Error: 1153  Got a packet
>   bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

How to get rid of this error, im using **Navicat mysql** and **WAMP server**??
In running scripts i choose continue on error so scripts still running with error msgs and values in Message log. Will this work and can i run the error values later??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try using these commands from mysql terminal

```
set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000; 
set global net_buffer_length=1000000;
```

Comment: can you pls tell me about will the table work and can i slove the errors value in anyway??

Comment: changing these values as mentioned in the answer should allow you to execute large sql scripts.Did you try these?

Comment: @ ayush yes its working but the file im doing to is too large so the scripts missed before i want to do them separately will it work like that?

Comment: can u please clarify your last comment.what exact problem are you facing now?

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from ayush solves it, but if you un-check the option "Run multiple queries in each execution" in the dialog box when executing SQL file it might do the trick as well (but the execution will take longer to run).